# How to change font size of Content Assist (Proposals) in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, font-size, content-assist

Is there a plugin to change the Font Size of the Content Assist (Proposals) I don't understand how Eclipse can let you change the font and color of everything except this...

[image: proposals extremely small from a distance]

Changing the system font is simply an unacceptable solution. I would have so much gratitude for someone who could develop a quick plugin to make this font size adjustable... or direct me in the direction to accomplish this. My eyes thank you.

Comment: I recommend IntelliJ's code assist. It's much-much better.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk so how do I get this other IDE's code assist into Eclipse :p I just want the font size to be bigger!

Comment: I don't know. Eclipse is annoying. I was just offering you an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only way you can do this, is by increasing the IDE font size globally.

Heres' how:
Inside the Eclipse.app is a setting for the font size. To make the fonts globally larger edit Eclipse.app » Contents » Eclipse » eclipse.ini and remove the line

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

from the file (if there are multiple, delete them all). Save the file and restart Eclipse.

Original post found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/how-to-increase-font-size-of-eclipse-globally

It worked on Mac, and I think it should work on Windows as well.

Comment: Please don't just post a link as the answer becomes invalid if the link becomes corrupt

Comment: Sorry, just editted my post. Thank you for your suggestion.